# How to customize Column Title area in Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, design, style-library

Good day!

Here is the problem:

I apply custom style to web parts

my css

```
.ms-vh-div  a
{
    color:gray !important;
}
.ms-vh-div 
{
    border-bottom: 1px #c0c0c0 solid; 
}

tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh,tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2
{
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh:hover,tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2:hover
{
    background-color:transparent;
}
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th:hover .s4-ctx-show
{
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:none;
    border:0px solid #e0e0e0;   
}
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th .s4-ctx-show:hover
{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

But when i test it the area with checkbox or with attachment stay the same(grayed area must be white):

[image: checkbox has not changed]

[image: attachment has no changed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify this class :-

**.ms-vh-icon**

Apply an override with the background-color:#fff !important and background-image:none.

Comment: Thank you, now everything is white. Could you give me an advice where to find information about css styles for sharepoint?

Comment: This should get you started comfortably for SP 2010 branding :-
http://sp2010notes.wordpress.com/sharepoint-2010-css-chart/

http://www.thesharepointmuse.com/sharepoint-2010-branding/

http://www.amazon.com/dp/0470584645?tag=blogdrisgillc-20&camp=14573&creative=327641&linkCode=as1&creativeASIN=0470584645&adid=0548M63A7184RVSZ5XD7&&ref-refURL=http://blog.drisgill.com/